# Storing Paint in a Hot Garage

Tags: safety

Safety in storing Paint.
I just purchased a new Gemini Twin Home or Duplex?
Is it safe to store Paint in a Garage where the heat could rise to 110 Degrees?
What can I do to get the paint out of my Garage. Drop it off to a paint store?
I attempted to have my Garbage removal service take the 3 cans and they would not?

Comment: In the US most municipalities have a hazardous waste disposal process. Check with them.

Comment: Latex paint would not be an issue but oil based that’s getting warm enough to cause the solvent to go to the vapor state, if well sealed it is not a hazard but if the can leaks close to an ignition source like a furnace or water heater with a pilot or flame even an electric with a contactor small sparks are generated but the proximity and volume of paint compared to the garage would have to be large to pose a hazard even with oil based but no problem with laytex. Unless you live in California then the can itself poses a cancer risk.

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify what sort of paint it is.

Answer (score 2):

1. Store the paint at/near floor level - unlikely it is that hot down there. Likely want to put it on plastic or wood rather than directly on concrete for corrosion reasons, if metal cans.
2. If it's latex (water based) no issue.
3. If you consider it trash, just pour it out on cardboard or
   newspaper and let it dry, leave the can open and let that dry,
   flatten the can, and put in a trash bag once all is throughly dry.
4. But consider "free paint" in your classified ad method of choice. Or at the side of the road.

Many areas do have one or several "Household hazardous waste collection days" per year.

Many areas have a place (typically at the transfer station or recycling depot) where you can drop off or pick up excess Latex paint rather than throw it away (or directly try to find someone to take it for free.)

If (as it sounds) the paint was included with your new home, it's good to have for any needed repairs around the home until it goes bad from old age, since it's the same paint & colors used in the home in the first place.